# Import data from user .csv file into table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, csv

In a Ruby on Rails web app, I want to import a .csv file from a user and the data present in the .csv file will be inserted into the `questions` table, but I'm getting errors when I run the application.

The app is working fine when I remove code written in `question.rb` and in the `html.erb` file.

Controller code:
**questions_controller.rb**

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  filter_access_to :all

  def import
    @question = Question.new
    @question.import(params[:file])

    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      @question.save! row.to_hash
    end

    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Questions imported succefully."
  end

end
```

Model code:
**question.rb**

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    @question.save! row.to_hash
  end
end
```

View code:
**question_type_listing.html.erb**

```
<fieldset class="formContainer">
  <legend><%=t('question.select_qtype_cat')%></legend>

  <%= form_tag({:action => "import"}, {:id => "class_form"}, multipart: true) do %>

    <span style="width: 130px; float: left;"><p><label for="upload_file">Select File</label> :</span>
    <%= file_field_tag :file %>
    <%= submit_tag "Import CSV" %>
  <% end %>

</fieldset>
```

Can someone suggest a way to fix this?

Comment: your logic seems weird. @question is an instance of Question. Then you are saving each row again and again to the same instance.

Comment: Please read a tutorial on ruby programming. It will teach you the differences between classes and their instances. Then look at this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel

Comment: @gaurav.singharoy   bro, please help me to do this . please tell the code  how to add .csv file into questions table , or we can use sql query if means how we can use . i am new to ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1:**

If you are trying to save all questions in the .csv, it can be achieved by only the following controller `questions_controller.rb` code, and `question.rb` function `import` is not needed:

```
def import
  file = params[:file]

  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    @question = Question.new
    @question.save! row.to_hash
  end

  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Questions imported succefully."
end
```

**Case 2:**

If you want the code to be in model (Rails convention), write the controller `questions_controller.rb`:

```
def import
  Question.import(params[:file])
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Questions imported succefully."
end
```

and model `question.rb`

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    question = Question.new
    question.save! row.to_hash
  end
end
```